# Using inner join between two dataframes but to get specific number of rows

Tags: r

Here is a Video i made just in case the text is confusing
https://youtu.be/wkVg4dJQHgc

I had two dataframes named **df1** and **df2**. Both of these dataframes contain different types of questions for educational tests which **measure** something and have a specific **format**

```
df1<-structure(list(Measures = c("space and shape", "space and shape", 
    "space and shape", "space and shape", "space and shape", "change and relationships", 
    "change and relationships", "change and relationships", "change and relationships", 
    "change and relationships", "space and shape", "space and shape", 
    "space and shape", "space and shape", "uncertainty and data", 
    "quantity", "uncertainty and data", "uncertainty and data", "uncertainty and data", 
    "quantity", "change and relationships", "change and relationships", 
    "space and shape", "space and shape", "space and shape", "quantity", 
    "quantity", "quantity", "quantity", "quantity", "uncertainty and data", 
    "change and relationships", "quantity", "quantity", "uncertainty and data", 
    "change and relationships", "uncertainty and data", "quantity", 
    "change and relationships", "change and relationships", "quantity", 
    "quantity", "quantity", "quantity", "quantity", "quantity", "change and relationships", 
    "uncertainty and data", "change and relationships", "uncertainty and data", 
    "uncertainty and data", "uncertainty and data", "quantity", "quantity", 
    "quantity", "space and shape", "change and relationships", "quantity", 
    "space and shape", "space and shape", "change and relationships", 
    "change and relationships", "uncertainty and data", "uncertainty and data", 
    "quantity", "change and relationships", "quantity", "change and relationships", 
    "space and shape", "quantity", "quantity", "quantity", "space and shape", 
    "space and shape", "space and shape", "uncertainty and data", 
    "uncertainty and data", "uncertainty and data", "change and relationships", 
    "change and relationships", "change and relationships", "uncertainty and data", 
    "uncertainty and data", "uncertainty and data", "change and relationships", 
    "change and relationships", "change and relationships", "change and relationships", 
    "change and relationships", "uncertainty and data", "space and shape", 
    "space and shape", "uncertainty and data", "uncertainty and data", 
    "uncertainty and data", "uncertainty and data", "uncertainty and data", 
    "quantity", "quantity", "space and shape", "space and shape", 
    "space and shape", "space and shape", "change and relationships", 
    "space and shape", "space and shape", "quantity", "change and relationships", 
    "change and relationships"), Format = c("Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Auto-coded", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Complex Multiple Choice", "Complex Multiple Choice", 
    "Complex Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Complex Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Complex Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Constructed Response Auto-coded", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Complex Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Manual", "Simple Multiple Choice", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", 
    "Complex Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Auto-coded", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Complex Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Expert", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Expert", "Simple Multiple Choice", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Simple Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Expert", "Simple Multiple Choice", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Complex Multiple Choice", "Complex Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Simple Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Expert", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Complex Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Complex Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", "Simple Multiple Choice", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Manual", "Simple Multiple Choice", 
    "Constructed Response Expert", "Constructed Response Manual", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Manual", "Complex Multiple Choice"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -109L), class = "data.frame")
    






   df2<- structure(list(Measures = c("space and shape", "space and shape", 
"space and shape", "space and shape"), Format = c("Constructed Response Expert", 
"Constructed Response Manual", "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Auto-coded"
)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I use this code to subset all the rows of first dataframe which are present in second dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)
inner_join(df1, df2)
```

But suppose that my df2 actually looked like this with an extra column at the end which tells me how many of these kinds of rows do i want from df1. For example in the following image it says that i want **2 questions** which MEASURE **space and shape** and are of format **constructed response format**

```
 df2<- structure(list(Measures = c("space and shape", "space and shape", 
    "space and shape", "space and shape", "asdaf"), Format = c("Constructed Response Expert", 
    "Constructed Response Manual", "Simple Multiple Choice", "Constructed Response Auto-coded", 
    "asfas"), Number = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 0)), row.names = c("1", "2", 
    "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Before this i got 9 types of such questions. But i want 2 such types of questions.

Comment: please dont ever post images of data, but rather code for the data. You had already provided the code, so the images are just vexing and not helping anyone. If necessary provide formated tables as text

Comment: i will remember that in future. I have also added a video rather than too many pictures so that my problem can be understood easily.

Comment: You should not do that (add videos) either. Just post CODE for the data.

Comment: Why not ? Its easier to explain my problem through videos rather than with words. English isnt my first langauge so i find it very hard to put these things into words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

inner_join(df1,df2) %>% 
  group_by(Measures, Format) %>% 
  slice(n=1:min(Number)) %>% 
  ungroup

#> Joining, by = c("Measures", "Format")
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   Measures        Format                          Number
#>   <chr>           <chr>                            <dbl>
#> 1 space and shape Constructed Response Auto-coded      1
#> 2 space and shape Constructed Response Expert          2
#> 3 space and shape Constructed Response Expert          2
#> 4 space and shape Constructed Response Manual          1
#> 5 space and shape Simple Multiple Choice               2
#> 6 space and shape Simple Multiple Choice               2
```

Comment: Can you explain why did we use min() in slice? if i have three numbers 1 2 3 then min would return me 1 because 1 is minimum. I am having trouble understanding why min is used here

Comment: You are welcome, @ujjwaltyagi! Inside each group, `Number` is a vector with all elements being equal. Hence, the minimum is the value of each one of such a values -- they are all equal. One could have used maximum as well! Is that now clear?

Comment: makes total sense thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you could help me out with this one too as it is directly related(and if it isnt answered by the time you see it) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70139451/find-how-much-of-df1-is-not-available-in-df2

Comment: @ujjwaltyagi: Someone else has meanwhile answered your question. Is that what you wanted?